# std::vector clear or swap with new vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Sometimes I detect in different c++ projects code like this:

```
std::vector<DataClass> _dataVec;
...

std::vector<DataClass>().swap(_dataVec);
```

Is this code more effective than obvious and simple clear call

```
_dataVec.clear();
```

or these code samples have some kind of difference?

For what purpose I should prefer first variant?